# Container resize is not working when placed inside stack widget

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, resize

I have one container(A) and its wrapped inside a Draggable widget. In the child of the container, I have one small container(B) wrapped with GestureDetector which helps in resizing the big container(A) by dragging the small container(B) placed at the bottom right.

Currently, if I try to resize the container (A) by dragging the small container(B), the big container(A) is dragged to a new position instead of being resized.

Any idea on this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Resize(),
    );
  }
}
class Resize extends StatefulWidget {
  const Resize({super.key});
  @override  _ResizeState createState() => _ResizeState();
}
class _ResizeState extends State<Resize> {
  double height = 30;
  double width = 100;
  double x = 100;
  double y = 100;
  int count = 0;
  Widget container() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.lightGreen,
      width: width,
      height: height,
    );
  }
  @override  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: const Text('Resize Demo'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: y,
              left: x,
              child: Draggable(
                  onDragEnd: (details) {
                    setState(() {
                      x = details.offset.dx;
                      y = details.offset.dy;
                    });
                  },
                  feedback: Container(
                    color: Colors.lightGreen,
                    height: height,
                    width: width,
                  ),
                  child: resizeContainer(container())),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
  Widget resizeContainer(Widget formField) {
    double initX = 0;
    double initY = 0;
    return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) =>          Container(
          height: height + 30,
          width: width + 30,
          child: Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children: [
              CustomPaint(
                painter: DashedBorder(),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: height, width: width, child: formField)),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  right: -2.5,
                  bottom: -2.5,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onVerticalDragStart: (details) {
                      initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
                      initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
                    },
                    onHorizontalDragStart: (details) {
                      initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
                      initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
                    },
                    onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
                      setState(() {
                        final dx = details.globalPosition.dx - initX;
                        final dy = details.globalPosition.dy - initY;
                        height = (height + dy).clamp(20, double.infinity);
                        width = (width + dx).clamp(50, double.infinity);
                        initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
                      initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
                      });
                    },
                    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                      setState(() {
                        final dx = details.globalPosition.dx - initX;
                        final dy = details.globalPosition.dy - initY;
                        height = (height + dy).clamp(20, double.infinity);
                        width = (width + dx).clamp(50, double.infinity);
                        initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
                      initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 14,
                          width: 14,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                  ),
            ])));
  }
}
class DashedBorder extends CustomPainter {
  DashedBorder({this.color});
  Color? color;
  @override  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = color ?? Colors.blue      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.square      ..strokeWidth = 1;
    _dashedLine(canvas, size, paint);
  }
  @override  bool shouldRepaint(covariant DashedBorder oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
  void _dashedLine(Canvas canvas, Size size, Paint paint) {
    const int dashWidth = 4;
    const int dashSpace = 5;
    double startX = 0;
    const double y = 0;
    double startY = 0;
    while (
        size.width > size.height ? startX < size.width : startY < size.height) {
      if (startX < size.width) {
        canvas.drawLine(
            Offset(startX, y), Offset(startX + dashWidth, y), paint);
        canvas.drawLine(Offset(startX, size.height),
            Offset(startX + dashWidth, size.height), paint);
      }
      if (startY < size.height) {
        canvas.drawLine(
            Offset(y, startY), Offset(y, startY + dashWidth), paint);
        canvas.drawLine(Offset(size.width, startY),
            Offset(size.width, startY + dashWidth), paint);
      }
      // Update the starting X and Starting Y.      startX += dashWidth + dashSpace;
      startY += dashWidth + dashSpace;
    }
  }
}
```